# message-mode: delete recipient easily

Tags: email, message

When I'm composing a message in `message-mode` I sometimes want to remove a recipient from a long list of recipients on the `To:` line.  It seems that there is no semantic kill command that would delete a complete recipient.

I could zap to the next delimiter, I suppose, but the different formats available for recipients and their display names makes this a lot harder.  When on a `To:`, `Cc:` or `Bcc:` line, I really don't need to be able to delete words or sentences or s-expressions, I just need to be able to remove a recipient as a syntactic unit.

How can I easily augment `kill-sexp` to remove a recipient (i.e. name and email address in the various common formats) when I'm on a recipient line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message-kill-address` (`C-c M-k`) gets you most of the way there: it will kill from point to the end of the address.  You would need to advise/adapt it to go to the beginning of the address to have complete functionality.

For what it's worth, `message-kill-address` relies internally on `message-skip-to-next-address`, but as far as I can tell, there's no analogous `message-skip-to-previous-address`.  You could probably adapt the former to get a working version of the latter.